# Saving Aliases for powershell in Visual Studio code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to both visual studio code and PowerShell, mostly used gitBash before. I'm just wondering if there is a way to save aliases that I set in the powershell, so I don't have to redo them everytime I restart the application.

I tried a few google searches but could not find the answer to my question.

Thank you.

S

Comment: Can you please expand better and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to **place [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) definitions** (or [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions)) in your **user-specific [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file**.

However, the specific solution  **depends on *how you're using PowerShell*** in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

- If you're using **PowerShell as a *general-purpose shell*** in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal:

  - First make sure that the file - and its directory - exist:

    ```bash
    if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { New-Item -Force $PROFILE }
    ```
  - Then open it for editing as follows:

    ```bash
    code $PROFILE
    ```
  - Any alias and function definitions you place in there will be available in future PowerShell sessions (of the same PowerShell edition).
- If - preferably<sup>[1]</sup> - you're using the **[PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)**, you're using the **PIC** **(PowerShell-Integrated Console)** in the integrated terminal, which **has *its own* `$PROFILE` file**, separate from those of stand-alone PowerShell installations.

  - You can open it from the PIC as follows (if it doesn't exist, create it with `New-Item -Force $PROFILE`, as above):

    ```bash
    psedit $PROFILE
    ```
  - Any alias and function definitions you place in there will be available in future PIC sessions by default - but *only* there.
  - Alternatively / complementarily, to **share definitions with a stand-alone PowerShell installation**, [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) *its* `$PROFILE` file (assuming it was created) add the following statement:

    - for the current user's *Windows PowerShell* profile, use:

      ```bash
      . ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
      ```
    - for the current user's *PowerShell (Core) 7+* profile, use:

      ```bash
      . ~\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
      ```

---

<sup>[1] The PowerShell extension provides a superior experience for *authoring* and *debugging* PowerShell code.</sup>

Comment: Hello,
Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. When using the psedit command I get the following response:

"psedit : The term 'psedit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or       
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is  
correct and try again."

And I looked in my Documents folder, but could not find either WindowsPowerShell nor a PowerShell folder.

Comment: @SkitzFist, looks like I never answered - sorry. Please see my update. Your symptoms imply that you aren't using the PowerShell extension of Visual Studio Code. I've added a solution for that scenario too.

Answer (score 0):

Short version to get you started

1. Open powershell as administrator and run

> new-item $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts -ItemType file -Force

2. Run

> notepad $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts

3. Add the following line to run git status with the alias gs

> function gs { git status }

Save and open vs code terminal (Hopefully you have powershell as your default cmd), run gs

Long Version

Read the article on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/